# Filtering out keys from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jsonpath

I have a JavaScript object in the below format

```
{
"Node1": [
    {
    "Node2": "node2detail1",
    "Node3": "node3detail1",
    "Node4": [
        "node4detail1",
        ]
    },
    {
    "Node2": "node2detail2",
    "Node3": "node3detail2",
    "Node4": [
        "node4detail2",
        ]
    },
    {
    "Node2": "node2detail3",
    "Node3": "node3detail3",
    "Node4": [
        "node4detail3",
        ]
    }
]}
```

Is it possible to write an jsonpath expression which would result in a JavaScript object in the following format?
The intention is to filter by keys.

```
{
"Node1": [
    {
    "Node2": "node2detail1",
    "Node3": "node3detail1",
    },
    {
    "Node2": "node2detail2",
    "Node3": "node3detail2",
    },
    {
    "Node2": "node2detail3",
    "Node3": "node3detail3",
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jsonpath is for extracting values, not filtering JavaScript objects. You can filter your object with:

```
{Node1: obj.Node1.map(function(o) { return {Node2: o.Node2, Node3: o.Node3}; })}
```

If you prefer to use Underscore, there is `_.pick`:

```
{Node1: _.map(obj.Node1, function(o) { return _.pick(o, 'Node2', 'Node3'); })}
```

If ES6/Harmony is your thing, define the map function as an arrow function with deconstructed parameters and implicit return value using simplified object literal syntax:

```
{Node1: obj.Node1.map(({Node2, Node3}) => ({Node2, Node3}))}
```

Destructively transform:

```
obj.Node1.forEach(function(o) { delete o.Node4; })
```

If it suits your fancy, you can use the property filtering capability of `JSON.stringify`. The array specifies keys to be serialized into the JSON string; others are ignored.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, ['Node1', 'Node2', 'Node3']))
```

Or you could specify a replacer function (taking key and value parameters) and kill `Node4` by returning`undefined` which means to skip that key and its value:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, function(k, v) { if (k !== 'Node4') return v; }))
```

Comment: This is incredibly thorough.